# Processing large time-series data

Tags: python, performance, datetime, pandas

I am currently processing some large time-series data with pandas, and I have a function that is intolerably slow, and I'm sure it could be done faster.

The problem is: I'm studying a factory that produces things. It runs continuously throughout the week, but on weekends it shuts down. Before the end of the week, and at the start of a new one, the factory behaves differently, which interferes with the analysis that I'm doing, and so I want to filter out a time window around these weekends.

I have a large dataframe, call it `df`, whose rows are the articles produced and the columns are their various attributes, one of which is the time at which it was produced, `df['timeProduced'`]. These articles are produced at irregularly-spaced points in time.I want to discard the rows in the table whose `timeProduced` entry was near one of these shutdown periods. The actual data is confidential, but it looks similar to this:

```
index   partId        colour   timeProduced  \ ...
1       '026531|352'  Red    2017-02-01 00:00:02   
2       '026531|353'  Blue   2017-02-01 00:00:03   
3       '026531|354'  Blue   2017-02-01 00:00:05   
4       '026531|355'  Green  2017-02-01 00:00:09
```

This  takes tens of minutes to crunch through a million entries. I know it's slow because it isn't at all vectorized, but I'm not sure how to do a pure vectorized numpy/pandas implementation. Any ideas?

```
def dropIrregularGaps(series, gapLength, runIn):
    '''
    Designed for time-series data where there is points sampled at irregular time intervals.
    Detects adjacent points that are sampled too far apart, and then removes points on either 
    side of the gap which are within a defined runIn period.
    Assumes timeseries data is already sorted. If not, will deliver garbage. 
    series is a pandas series object, with values as pandas DateTime objects.
    gapLength is the amount of time that is considered to be a shutdown
    runIn is the length of time to remove on either side of the gap.
    returns a list of indices that are valid
    '''
    samples = list(series)
    indices = list(series.index)

    prev = samples[0]
    ind = indices[0]
    allGoodIndices = []
    currentGoodIndices = [ind]
    currentGoodTimes = [prev]
    skipPoint = None

    for new, ind in zip(samples[1:], indices[1:]):
        if skipPoint:
            if new - skipPoint >= runIn:
                # if a gap has been detected, skip over all points until the current
                # point is past the run-in period.
                skipPoint = None
                currentGoodIndices = [ind]
                currentGoodTimes = [new]

        elif new - prev > gapLength:
            # if a gap is detected. cut out the cooldown period from the list,
            # and add what remains to the list of goodIndices.
            endPoint = currentGoodTimes[-1]
            while currentGoodTimes and (endPoint - currentGoodTimes[-1] < runIn):
                del (currentGoodTimes[-1])
                del (currentGoodIndices[-1])

            allGoodIndices += currentGoodIndices
            currentGoodIndices = []
            currentGoodTimes = []
            skipPoint = new
        else:
            currentGoodIndices += [ind]
            currentGoodTimes += [new]

        prev = new

    allGoodIndices += currentGoodIndices

    return allGoodIndices
```

I operate this function by taking my dataframe, and running:

```
result = dropIrregularGaps(df['timeProduced'],pd.Timedelta('4 hours'), pd.Timedelta('8 hours 0 minutes'))
```

I then use the result to index into the dataframe, giving me the dataframe without the startup/cooldown periods.

```
df = df.loc[result]
```

Comment: I suspect you want to look into dataframe.[resample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html#pandas.DataFrame.resample), though I'm not sure because I don't fully understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: can you share some sample data to experiment on?

Comment: Why exactly are you not filtering the data with a specialized timeseries database or similar before crunching it with python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Some general tips

### functions

split the work in functions, so you can verify each part individually, each doing a specific job which can be individually tested

### PEP-8

Try to follow the guidelines

## My algorithm

If your pandas version is >= 0.20, you can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge_asof.html) If you have a series with the end and start of the work week

## dummy data

```
np.random.seed(1)
gap_max, run_in = 3, 2
indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18]
values = np.random.random(size = len(indices))
data = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'values': values})
```

> ```
>      time  values
> 0     0   0.417022004702574
> 1     1   0.7203244934421581
> 2     2   0.00011437481734488664
> 3     3   0.30233257263183977
> 4     7   0.14675589081711304
> 5     8   0.0923385947687978
> 6     9   0.1862602113776709
> 7     13  0.34556072704304774
> 8     15  0.39676747423066994
> 9     16  0.538816734003357
> 10    17  0.4191945144032948
> 11    18  0.6852195003967595
> ```

so for this data, we expect the values of 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15 dropped

## Finding the gaps

The gap can be found by using `DataFrame.shift`.

```
def find_weekend(times, gap_max):
    gap = times - times.shift(1) > gap_max
    week_start = times[gap]
    weekend_start = times[gap.shift(-1).fillna(False)]
    return weekend_start, week_start
find_weekend(data['time'], gap_max)
```

> ```
>  3    3
>  6    9
>  Name: index, dtype: int64, 
>  4     7
>  7    13
>  Name: index, dtype: int64
> ```

Marking the start of the data as the beginning of a week can be done by adding `gap.iloc[0] = True` as 2nd line. Marking the end of the data as also an end of the week can be done by changing to `.fillna(True)`

## merging with the data

Since `merge_asof` expects `DataFrame`s, we first need to do some transformation

```
def drop_irregular_gaps(data, gap_max, run_in):
    weekend_start, week_start = find_weekend(data[time_label], gap_max)
    df_week_end = weekend_start.to_frame(name=time_label).assign(run_out=True)
    df_week_start = week_start.to_frame(name=time_label).assign(run_in=True)
    df_data = data[[time_label]]
```

Then we can use 2 merges, one forward to mark the end of the week, one backward to mark the beginning of the week

```
    before_weekend = pd.merge_asof(
        df_data, df_week_end, 
        on=time_label, direction='forward', tolerance=run_in,
    ).set_index(time_label)['run_out'].fillna(False).values
    after_weekend = pd.merge_asof(
        df_data, df_week_start, 
        on=time_label, direction='backward', tolerance=run_in,
    ).set_index(time_label)['run_in'].fillna(False).values
```

These are 2 array with `True` as value if they are in a run_in or run_out period

> ```
> array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
>         False, False, False], dtype=bool),
>  array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
>         False, False, False], dtype=bool)
> ```

Next we just us an `or` and `not` for the boolean indexing

```
    to_drop = before_weekend | after_weekend
    return data[~to_drop]

drop_irregular_gaps(data, gap_max, run_in)
```

> ```
>       time    values
> 0     0       0.417022004702574
> 9     16      0.538816734003357
> 10    17      0.4191945144032948
> 11    18      0.6852195003967595
> ```

This can be easily adapted to 2 separate values for the `run_in`

## Datetime data

The algorithm should be agnostic about whether the `time_label` data is numeric or datetime. I verified this algorithm also works with this dummy data

```
data_start = pd.Timestamp('20180101')
time = data_start + pd.to_timedelta([0, 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 17, 18], unit='day')
gap_max, run_in = pd.to_timedelta(3, unit='day'), pd.to_timedelta(2, unit='day')
values = np.random.random(size = len(indices))
data = pd.DataFrame({'time': time, 'values': values})
drop_irregular_gaps(data, gap_max, run_in)
```

> ```
>       time        values
> 0     2018-01-01  0.417022004702574
> 9     2018-01-17  0.538816734003357
> 10    2018-01-18  0.4191945144032948
> 11    2018-01-19  0.6852195003967595
> ```

## alternative without `merge_asof`

Since apparently `merge_asof` doesn't work as good with duplicate data, here a variant with a loop. If there are a lot of weekends, this might be slower, but I reckon it will still be faster than the original code

```
def mark_runin(time, week_endpoints, run_in, direction='backward'):
    mask = np.zeros_like(time, dtype=bool)
    for point in week_endpoints:
        interval = (point, point + run_in) if direction == 'forward' else (point - run_in, point)
        mask |= time.between(*interval).values
    return mask
mark_runin(time, weekend_start, run_in)
```

> ```
> array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
> ```

```
def drop_irregular_gaps2(data, gap_max, run_in, time_label = 'time'):
    times = data[time_label]
    weekend_start, week_start = find_weekend(times, gap_max)
    before_weekend = mark_runin(times, weekend_start, run_in, direction = 'backward')
    after_weekend = mark_runin(times, week_start, run_in, direction = 'forward')
    to_drop = before_weekend | after_weekend
    return data[~to_drop]
drop_irregular_gaps2(data, gap_max, run_in)
```

> ```
>   time        values
> 0 2018-01-01  0.417022004702574
> 9 2018-01-17  0.538816734003357
> 10    2018-01-18  0.4191945144032948
> 11    2018-01-19  0.6852195003967595
> ```

Comment: This solution is really good! It's almost perfect, but when the dataset contains rows that have exactly the same timestamps, it delivers a 'ValueError: left keys must be sorted' . Is there an easy way around this?

Comment: Never mind, the ValueError came from somewhere else.